# how can i make a button invisible for some users in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to make a button invisible for some users (logins). Is that even possible? That means when i start the program if the user login is, for an example, Jack, he cant see the button and can't use it. For some other user the button should be visible and he should be able to use it.

Comment: You're going to want to read up on [Access Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Okuma.Scott considering the way the question is written Access Tokens might be overkill..

Comment: @christian.s Well the OP doesn't specify what type of "logins" he's using, so I assume he means Windows user accounts.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott good point, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a property where you save the value if the user is allowed to use the button or not.. you can use the "Enabled" or the "Visible"(might be "IsVisible") to control access.. When creating the control, you should check for the user rights and can enable/disable buttons/controls etc...

Pseudo Code:

```
bool userIsPermitted = GetUserPermission(currentuser);
InitializeControls(userIsPermitted);

...

InitializeControls(bool isAllowedToUseControls)
{
   button1.Visibility = isAllowedToUseControls;
   button1.Enabled = isAllowedToUseControls;
}
```

However, if you want to create a more complex rights system, you should spend more effort on looking around here (or google..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a simple way you can put a condition and set the visibility to false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a data storage (plain file, XML doc or database) and specify User's permissions (sometimes called 'User Entitlements'). Then, based on that data, set the Visibility property (either Visible, or Hidden, or Collapsed) of the respective Controls. Also, you can set the Enabled=false property (Control could be still visible but disabled). Rgds,

Comment: Not a very good method if you care about security _at all_.

Comment: @Ocuma.Scott: Security concerns are not mentioned in original requirements. Depends on actual requirements, the level of data protection/security can be increased (including the highest one which implies secure database with encryption - it's in my post). Rgds,

Comment: Good point. The OP's question does not mention security.